# Mathematica integral with many singularities

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, calculus

What's the best way of getting Mathematica 7 or 8 to do the integral

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi x], {x, 0, 50}]
```

There are poles at every integer - and we want the Cauchy principle value.
The idea is to get a good approximation for the integral from 0 to infinity.

With `Integrate` there is the option `PrincipleValue -> True`.

With `NIntegrate` I can give it the option `Exclusions -> (Sin[Pi x] == 0)`, or manually give it the poles by

```
NIntegrate[Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi x], Evaluate[{x, 0, Sequence@@Range[50], 50}]]
```

The original command and the above two `NIntegrate` tricks give the result `60980 +/- 10`. But they all spit out errors. What is the best way of getting a quick reliable result for this integral without Mathematica wanting to give errors?

Comment: FYI if I try different WorkingPrecision values I get totally different results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simon, is there reason to believe your integral is convergent ?

```
In[52]:= f[k_Integer, eps_Real] := 
 NIntegrate[Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi x], {x, k + eps, k + 1 - eps}]

In[53]:= Sum[f[k, 1.0*10^-4], {k, 0, 50}]

Out[53]= 2.72613

In[54]:= Sum[f[k, 1.0*10^-5], {k, 0, 50}]

Out[54]= 3.45906

In[55]:= Sum[f[k, 1.0*10^-6], {k, 0, 50}]

Out[55]= 4.19199
```

It looks like the problem is at x==0. Splitting integrand k+eps to k+1-eps for integer values of k:

```
In[65]:= int = 
 Sum[(-1)^k Exp[-k ], {k, 0, Infinity}] Integrate[
   Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi x], {x, eps, 1 - eps}, Assumptions -> 0 < eps < 1/2]

Out[65]= (1/((1 + 
   E) (I + \[Pi])))E (2 E^(-1 + eps - I eps \[Pi])
     Hypergeometric2F1[1, (I + \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi]), 3/2 + I/(2 \[Pi]), 
     E^(-2 I eps \[Pi])] + 
   2 E^(I eps (I + \[Pi]))
     Hypergeometric2F1[1, (I + \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi]), 3/2 + I/(2 \[Pi]), 
     E^(2 I eps \[Pi])])

In[73]:= N[int /. eps -> 10^-6, 20]

Out[73]= 4.1919897038160855098 + 0.*10^-20 I

In[74]:= N[int /. eps -> 10^-4, 20]

Out[74]= 2.7261330651934049862 + 0.*10^-20 I

In[75]:= N[int /. eps -> 10^-5, 20]

Out[75]= 3.4590554287709991277 + 0.*10^-20 I
```

As you see there is a logarithmic singularity.

```
In[79]:= ser = 
 Assuming[0 < eps < 1/32, FullSimplify[Series[int, {eps, 0, 1}]]]

Out[79]= SeriesData[eps, 0, {(I*(-1 + E)*Pi - 
     2*(1 + E)*HarmonicNumber[-(-I + Pi)/(2*Pi)] + 
          Log[1/(4*eps^2*Pi^2)] - 2*E*Log[2*eps*Pi])/(2*(1 + E)*Pi), 
     (-1 + E)/((1 + E)*Pi)}, 0, 2, 1]

In[80]:= Normal[
  ser] /. {{eps -> 1.*^-6}, {eps -> 0.00001}, {eps -> 0.0001}}

Out[80]= {4.191989703816426 - 7.603403526913691*^-17*I, 
 3.459055428805136 - 
     7.603403526913691*^-17*I, 
 2.726133068607085 - 7.603403526913691*^-17*I}
```

**EDIT**
Out[79] of the code above gives the series expansion for eps->0, and if these two logarithmic terms get combined, we get

```
In[7]:= ser = SeriesData[eps, 0, 
       {(I*(-1 + E)*Pi - 2*(1 + E)*HarmonicNumber[-(-I + Pi)/(2*Pi)] + 
              Log[1/(4*eps^2*Pi^2)] - 2*E*Log[2*eps*Pi])/(2*(1 + E)*
       Pi), 
         (-1 + E)/((1 + E)*Pi)}, 0, 2, 1]; 

In[8]:= Collect[Normal[PowerExpand //@ (ser + O[eps])], 
 Log[eps], FullSimplify]

Out[8]= -(Log[eps]/\[Pi]) + (
 I (-1 + E) \[Pi] - 
  2 (1 + E) (HarmonicNumber[-((-I + \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi]))] + 
     Log[2 \[Pi]]))/(2 (1 + E) \[Pi])
```

Clearly the -Log[eps]/Pi came from the pole at x==0. So if one subtracts this, just like principle value method does this for other poles you end up with a finitely value:

```
In[9]:= % /. Log[eps] -> 0

Out[9]= (I (-1 + E) \[Pi] - 
 2 (1 + E) (HarmonicNumber[-((-I + \[Pi])/(2 \[Pi]))] + 
    Log[2 \[Pi]]))/(2 (1 + E) \[Pi])

In[10]:= N[%, 20]

Out[10]= -0.20562403655659928968 + 0.*10^-21 I
```

Of course, this result is difficult to verify numerically, but you might know more that I do about your problem.

**EDIT 2**

This edit is to justify In[65] input that computes the original regularized integral. We are computing

```
Sum[ Integrate[ Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi*x], {x, k+eps, k+1-eps}], {k, 0, Infinity}] ==  
  Sum[ Integrate[ Exp[-x-k]/Sin[Pi*(k+x)], {x, eps, 1-eps}], {k, 0, Infinity}] ==
  Sum[ (-1)^k*Exp[-k]*Integrate[ Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi*x], {x, eps, 1-eps}], 
       {k, 0, Infinity}] == 
  Sum[ (-1)^k*Exp[-k], {k, 0, Infinity}] * 
     Integrate[ Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi*x], {x, eps, 1-eps}]
```

In the third line Sin[Pi*(k+x)] == (-1)^k*Sin[Pi*x] for integer k was used.

Comment: Hi Sasha, thanks for all of your work on this problem. I actually got this problem from a Mathematician who said that he uses Mma4 because it has a package that gives better support than the later built-in support for PrincipleValue numerical integrals. He gave me this example, and now that you've made me think more about it, I agree... it's not a good one!  The problem at lim x->+0 is because there isn't the corresponding lim x->-0 to cancel the pole.

Comment: I have a question about your `In[65]` where you define `int`. The `Sum` appears to be unrelated to everything else... I think this leads to problems in the rest of your analysis - **but** not your conclusions!

Comment: @Simon In[65] is easily justifiable by splitting integral 0..inf into 0+ .. 1- and 1+..2- and so on. Then it becomes a sum over k of integrals of Exp[-k-x]/Sin[Pi*(k+x)] for x from eps to 1-eps. But Sin[Pi*(k+x)] == (-1)^k*Sin[Pi*x] and the integrand becomes (-1)^k*Exp[-k]*Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi*x]. Thus the sum and integral can now be carried out independently as in In[65]. I your question makes it worth putting in an edit explaining this step.

Answer (score 4):

Simon, I haven't spent much time with your integral, but you should try looking at [stationary phase approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation). What you have is a smooth function (exp), and a highly oscillatory function (sine). The work involved is now in brow-beating the `1/sin(x)` into the form `exp(if(x))`

Alternatively, you could use the series expansion of the `cosecant` (not valid at poles):

```
In[1]:=Series[Csc[x], {x, 0, 5}]
(formatted) Out[1]=1/x + x/6 + 7/360 x^3 + 31/15120 x^5 +O[x]^6
```

Note that for all `m>-1`, you have the following:

```
In[2]:=Integrate[x^m Exp[-x], {x, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> m > -1]
Out[2]=Gamma[1+m]
```

However, summing the series with the coefficients of cosecant (from wikipedia), not including `1/x Exp[-x]` case, which doesn't converge on `[0,Infinity]`.

```
c[m_] := (-1)^(m + 1) 2 (2^(2 m - 1) - 1) BernoulliB[2 m]/Factorial[2 m];
Sum[c[m] Gamma[1 + 2 m - 1], {m, 1, Infinity}]
```

does not converge either...

So, I'm not sure that you can work out an approximation for the integral to infinity, but I if you're satisfied with a solution upto some large N, I hope these help.

Comment: Thanks R.M. The integral was a bad example given to me by someone whose math ability I trusted.... There's a pole at zero where we only take a one-sided limit. This means we can't get a PrincipleValue for this pole...

Answer (score 4):

I have to agree with [Sasha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575946/mathematica-integral-with-many-singularities/5576465#5576465), the integral does not appear to be convergent.  However, if you exclude `x == 0` and break the integral into pieces

```
Integrate[Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi x], {x, n + 1/2, n + 3/2}, PrincipalValue -> True]
```

where `n >= 0 && Element[n, Integers]`, then it seems you may get an alternating series

```
I Sum[ (-1/E)^n, {n, 1, Infinity}] == - I / (1 + E )
```

Now, I only took it out to `n == 4`, but it looks reasonable. However, for the integral above with `Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers] && n >= 0` Mathematica gives

```
If[ 2 n >= 1, - I / E, Integrate[ ... ] ]
```

which just doesn't conform to the individual cases.  As an additional note, if the pole lies at the boundary of the integration region, i.e. your limits are `{x, n, n + 1}`, you only get `DirectedInfinity`s.  A quick look at the plot implies that you with the limits `{x, n, n + 1}` you only have a strictly positive or negative integrand, so the infinite value may be due to the lack of compensation which `{x, n + 1/2, n + 3/2}` gives you. Checking with `{x, n, n + 2}`, however it only spits out the unevaluated integral.

Comment: I don't get an alternating series... rather one with all positive terms (see my answer above). The integral expands out to be a sum of `Gamma` functions (which is not convergent) plus an integral of `Exp[-x]/x` term, which is also not convergent due to the singularity at the origin.

Comment: @R. M., actually we're using different integration regions. I exclude the `x == 0` part by starting at `x == 1/2` and integrating over intervals 1 unit wide; the sum of which looks like an alternating series, which is convergent.

Comment: Thanks rcollyer. You're right, the x=0 point is a one sided limit that can't be balanced by the other side. And that `Integrate[Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi x], {x, n + 1/2, n + 3/2}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]` gives a complex constant times `(-1/E)^n`. But this doesn't match `NIntegrate[Exp[-x]/Sin[Pi x], {x, n + 1/2, n, n + 3/2}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 40]` which gives an answer highly dependent on the `WorkingPrecision`. All in all, it was a bad question/example.